# center align a circular image

Tags: html, css

I'm putting up circular pictures on my site this way:

HTML:

```
<table class="profiles-table">
    <td>
        <div class="david-circle profile-circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="david-circle profile-circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="david-circle profile-circle"></div>
    </td>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.profiles-table {
    width:100%;
}
table.profiles-table td {
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    width:33%;
}
div.david-circle {
    background: url(./images/david.jpg) no-repeat;
}
div.profile-circle {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
}
```

This doesn't center align the circle image.  If I replace the div with text, it's center aligned.  If I use img src="blah", it also works.  Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `background-position: center center`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS.

```css
table.profiles-table {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
table.profiles-table td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    width:33%;
}
div.david-circle {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/400) center center no-repeat;
}
div.profile-circle {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Apply `display: inline-block` to `.profile-circle` to that the horizontal centering works.

To center the background image, add `center center` to the background property.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/arknmb35/

I was not sure about the vertical centering so I left as is.

Answer (score -1):

add display:inline-block to divs

```
div.profile-circle {
  margin-bottom:30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-border-radius: 75px;
   display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: remove margin-bottom:30px; for vertical-align

Comment: div.profile-circle {
 
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-border-radius: 75px;
   display:inline-block
}